# Git interactive.singlekey from urxvt

Tags: terminal, git, urxvt

In git-config's docs it says (emphasis mine):

> interactive.singlekey In interactive commands, allow the user to
>   provide one-letter input with a single key (i.e., without hitting
>   enter). Currently this is used by the --patch mode of git-add(1),
>   git-checkout(1), git-commit(1), git-reset(1), and git-stash(1).
>   **Note that this setting is silently ignored if portable keystroke
>   input is not available**.

This setting doesn't work in urxvt, so I'll assume that "portable keystroke input" *isn't* available in urxvt. Is there a way to enable it? If so, is there any reason I wouldn't want to? (probably the reason it's not on by default; if it is implemented).

Thanks!

Note: this question was originally from [the arch bbs](https://bbs.archlinux.org/edit.php?id=1352297), but I didn't get any answers; so it's here now :)

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `apt-cache search term.*readkey`

the solution for me was to install `libterm-readkey-perl`:

`sudo aptitude install libterm-readkey-perl`

*(copied the answer from [http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/question-about-interactive-singlekey-td6765652.html)](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/question-about-interactive-singlekey-td6765652.html)_)*